# Multiple variables in Jenkins shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to print two variables in Jenkins shell (one of which is global one) . When I print them independently on shell for each it works, however when I try both variables on single line it fails. See the output, seems like a crop after the first variable .

I've tried to print two local variables, and it seems working. However I need the global one

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def START
node ('master') {
    // options{
    //     timestamps()
    // }
    stage("one") {
    script{
        START = sh(script: 'date --utc +%FT%T', returnStdout: true)
        }
    stage("two") {
        def END = sh(script: 'date --utc +%FT%T', returnStdout: true)
        sh "echo start $START"
        sh "echo end $END"
        sh "echo $START and $END"
        }
    }
}
```

```
+ date --utc +%FT%T
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo start 2019-08-01T14:48:08
start 2019-08-01T14:48:08
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo end 2019-08-01T14:48:09
end 2019-08-01T14:48:09
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 2019-08-01T14:48:08
2019-08-01T14:48:08
+ and 2019-08-01T14:48:09
/var/jenkins_home@tmp/durable-979e1b9e/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home@tmp/durable-979e1b9e/script.sh: and: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Try using `echo` or `print` instead of `sh 'echo'`.

Comment: might be the newline in date, try `START = sh(script: 'date --utc +%FT%T', returnStdout: true).trim()`

Answer (score 0):

`sh` is a dedicated command of jenkins-groovy. The first two work because $START/$END are the final string and doesn't try to replace something else.

`sh "echo ${START} and ${END}"` writing the variables like this will limit the GString and convert only the correct part and wont try to convert the "and" also.

For more have a look at this examples http://grails.asia/groovy-gstring-examples